Error When Connect SQL Server Management Studio 2012 Database With Apache Jmeter (Java version 22)
When connecting to SQL Server Management Studio 2012 Database with Apache Jmeter (Java version 22)
the following exception is thrown:
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.0.107,1434, port 1433 has failed.
    Error: "192.168.0.107,1434. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port.
    Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".)

I tried to add
;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false;sslProtocol=TLSv1.2

but it failed to stop the exception from being thrown.

It looks like a typo in your JDBC URL, you should use 192.168.0.107, please remove 1434 from the URL in JDBC Connection Configuration
If your MSSQL server is running on port 1434 you should set it via semicolon like:
jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.107:1434;encrypt=false;etc

Also make sure that TCP protocol is enabled (IIRC it's disabled by default) and if JMeter is running on another machine you might need to open the port in your operating system firewall
Also make sure to have the relevant version of MSSQL JDBC Driver in JMeter Classpath

192.168.0.107,1434. is wrong . 1434 should be given with semicolon 192.168.0.107:1434
